# how to keep form element inline with text on headline in HTML/css/boostrap 3?

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap3 in my HTML/css template;
Here is how my page looks like:[image]

I want the star to appear inline with the headline (that is right next to the text).
The star is button, upon clicking a form is submitted.
Here is my html code so far to get this:

```
<div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
  <h3>2004 Toyota Prius $7000 
   <form action="/post/unbookmark/" method="POST"> 
      <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='ME7CDsBM2mPw2uWSyV28rgQMbE5bEDG2' />
       <input type="hidden" name="bookmark_id" value="1839" />
       <button type="submit" class="bookmark" id="1839" ><span class= "glyphicon glyphicon-star">  </span>    </button>
    </form>
   </h3>
        <p><small>hello, i&#39;m selling 2004 toyota prius with 120k miles. with clear title 44-50 mpg really good on gas ! keyless ... </small></p>
         <p>
          <a class="btn btn-default" href="/search/1839/detail/" role="button">View details &raquo;</a>       
         </p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me using Bootstrap 3. If this doesn't work for you, check your `bookmark` class

```
<div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
    <form action="/post/unbookmark/" method="POST"> 
        <h3>2004 Toyota Prius $7000 <button type="submit" class="bookmark" id="1839"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span></button></h3>
        <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='ME7CDsBM2mPw2uWSyV28rgQMbE5bEDG2' />
        <input type="hidden" name="bookmark_id" value="1839" />
    </form>
    <p><small>hello, i&#39;m selling 2004 toyota prius with 120k miles. with clear title 44-50 mpg really good on gas ! keyless ... </small></p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="/search/1839/detail/" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
</p>
```